# Why should I use NgRx if I have Signal?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Angular has recently introduced Signals.

Given this new feature, what advantages does the NgRx component store or any other state management offer over Signals?

What capabilities does the NgRx component store provide that cannot be replicated with Signals, if any?

Why should I use NgRx if I have Signal?

Comment: NgRX isn't a "component" - it's _infrastructure_ - and I suspect transitioning to Angular Signals is going to be non-trivial - so my advice to you is to stick with NgRX unless you can make a solid case for moving to Signals.

Comment: I've dabbled in NgRx a few times myself. Considering the intricate challenges it introduces to the team, I've come to the conclusion that unless you're part of a sprawling team where standardized code is non-negotiable, or if you're in dire need of features like time travel, opting for something simpler to handle, like signals, is undoubtedly the wiser choice! But Im pretty sure you will find people defending by all means tools like NgRx. In the end is your decision. You need to consider the pros and cons :)

Comment: @Dai I thing they're referring to `@ngrx/component-store` which is an alternative to the service with a behaviour subject pattern

Answer (score 1):

### @ngrx/component-store

`@ngrx/component-store` **isn't** state management in the typical sense this term is used (global (or domain or feature) single source of truth which is what `@ngrx/store` and soon to be `@ngrx/signal-store` provide).

Read https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/comparison for more on this distinction which also gives an overview of things to consider before using it.

Specifically `@ngrx/component-store` now has limited advantages over using the primitives directly and something like [connect](https://ngxtension.netlify.app/utilities/signals/connect/) from ngxtension and the following pattern

```
class SomeComponent {
  private destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef)


  someMethod() {
    obs$.pipe(
      ...,
      takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)
    ).subscribe(...)
```

for cleaning up observables.

### @ngrx/store

Comparing using signals to `@ngrx/store` isn't really valid. It's a redux pattern for managing single source of truth state outside the lifecycle of a single component.

Ultimately whether to use a 3rd party library is an engineering decision - use your own judgement.

Comment: I think you are missing the component store purpose.
It's a local state management, like you said, not global
But it's still using the same "flow" than what we call broadly a "store" or more precisely "reactive store", it's not that much different.
You can still achieve "single source of truth" pattern by splitting your stores in several part, it's not a issue.
In the code you provide it's just reproducing the usual way of handling "reactive store" to store data just by using observable/subject, which is perfectly fine in fact, and was the way it was done before component store, already.